# Identifying organic compounds in Infrared spectrum

Tags: organic-chemistry

What further information would allow you to make a positive identification of an organic compound from an infrared spectrum?

Comment: I guess I would use NMR.

Comment: @orthocresol the question, however, asked about IR. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to confirm identity or elucidate the structure of a completely unknown compound?

Comment: @jerepierre confirm identity

Comment: @J.Doe Then what you need is an IR spectrum of an authentic sample.

Comment: Well, your question asked for "further" information... I think if you have a clue what sort of compound you're looking at (eg you isolated an intermediate in a synthesis which you know the structure of) then IR is useful as a means of confirmation since peaks will appear/disappear based on the presence/absence of specific functional groups. Although the gold standard, as @jerepierre mentions, would be to compare it to an IR spectrum of the pure compound.

Comment: That is like super-general question. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

If you're analyzing an IR spectrum to find out what compound you have, you'll first want to look past the 1500/cm region to see what functional groups you have. For example, a 1700/cm peak will tell you you have a carbonyl, alcohols will have a peak around 3000/cm, etc. From there, pull up spectra of well known compounds with those functional groups, and compare your compound's 1500/cm to 500/cm region to them. This region is called the "fingerprint region" because it's practically unique for all molecules, so if the spectra match there, they're likely the same compound.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare your IR spactra to a database entry. Usually, the database provides examples of spectra from a high purity sample and that way you can even see how pure your sample is.

Comment: This is better written as a comment

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). As @santiago (subtly?) points out, we expect our answers to be of a higher quality than this. Please be more elaborate.